# Excel ADOB SQL Recordsets, ORDER BY works on one xlsx file but not on others?

Tags: sql, excel, ado, vba

Why does ORDER BY work on some xlsx files and not on others?

I build SQL statements (using ADOB) to move data from closed workbooks (I need the speed and would like to use SQL to sort the data) into my active workbook.  Below are the two strings I use and both work perfectly for their associated files.

```
   mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "] ORDER BY " & TargetSortColumn & ";"   'This works for my data dictionary.

   mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"                                     'This works for the Cost File.
```

I cannot find any fundamental differences between the two files.  I am simply trying to copy a worksheet from each closed workbook into my current workbook and sort it with ORDER BY.

I always jump to my error trap, when using ORDER BY on my cost file.  When I hit the second statement below It triggers the error trap.

```
Set Con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Data = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

I have used the debugger to check and the parameters passed into this procedure are correct for each file.  I pass in all strings and use the strings to build the SQL statements so there is no mismatch there.

I have opened both files and resaved them to ensure their is no basic problem with the files.  I am using Excel 2010.

The worksheets in both files have their correct names passed into the subroutine correctly.

Both worksheets have data starting at cell(1,1).

Remember the two SQL statements work correctly for their respective files.

Why can I NOT use ORDER BY on some files?

I have agitated the little grey cells most vigorously on this problem, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comment out your `On Error Goto...` - what error message do you get when you run your code?  Would also help to update your question to show your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, but I don't know why, perhaps NULL cells crash the `ORDER BY` clause?

I added a `WHERE` clause that removed the rows that the column `code <> NULL` I could then use the `ORDER BY` code clause without difficulty.

```
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "]
         WHERE code <> NULL
         ORDER BY code;
```

That solved the issue.  I do not understand why `ORDER` is not working in my case with EMPTY values.  I simply expected them to be at the top of the sort order.

The `WHERE` clause is blindingly fast as compared to the VBA equivalent.

Anyway, By using the `WHERE` clause the SQL works most excellency!  The little grey cells are now at peace.

Craigm

Comment: THANKS for everyone's help.  I was really confused, it cost me a few hours of sleep.  Your input led me to create a bunch of vba code to test my hypostasis’s and to an appropriate solution.               Thanks again to all of you!  Craigm